# Yii2, parameters in url not working in action view

Tags: yii2

Im trying to build a simple view with extra options(parameters). When I use the /product/ and /product/index the view will show, but I want to add paramaters to select a post per id.

As im working inside a already build yii2 project maybe the settings are not correct or need to be set, i dont know but when I do use a parameter it will show me a page not found error(inside the layout).

```
www.example.com/products/ // view works
www.example.com/products/index/ // view works
www.example.com/products/id/extraparam //view not working (how I want it to be)
```

**controller**

```
public $defaultAction = 'index';

public function actionIndex( $id , $par)
{

    $proid = $id; // we want to use this if present
    $extra = $par; // we want to use this if present

    // as we do not need the layout 
    $this->layout = false;

    return $this->render('index');
}
```

Comment: Suggested reading: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing

Answer (score 1):

You will need to edit UrlManager settings in your main config.

```
'urlManagerFrontend'  => [
    'class'           => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
    'baseUrl'         => 'https://somedomain/', // if you want to prepend domain name to all links
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName'  => false,
    'rules'           => [
        '<module:[a-z-]+>/<controller:[a-z-]+>/<action:[a-z-]+>/<id:\d+>/<param:[a-z-]+>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',
        '<module:[a-z-]+>/<controller:[a-z-]+>/<action:[a-z-]+>'                          => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:[a-z-]+>/<id:\d+>'                                                   => '<controller>/view',
        '<controller:[a-z-]+>/<action:[a-z-]+>/<id:\d+>'                                  => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:[a-z-]+>/<action:[a-z-]+>/<id:\d+>/<param:[a-z-]+>'                  => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:[a-z-]+>/<action:[a-z-]+>'                                           => '<controller>/<action>',
    ],
],
```

you will have another param bound to some rules
(in this exapmple the **param** must match pattern `[a-z-]`)
to create urls you will need to specify the **param**:

```
Url::to(['product/edit', 'id' => 4, 'param' => 'sample-product']);
// this will link to:   /product/edit/4/sample-product
```

you can experiment with custom rules, use multiple params, and so on.

do remember that yii will always use the first rule that matches url matched

```
'<controller:[a-z-]+>/<id:\d+>/<param:[a-z-]>' => '<controller>/view' 
// this will match your exact case for actionView
```